# "java.net.connectionException" showing connection refused

Tags: java, email, servlets

I am trying to work on java mail api and have the following code in my servlet to sen mail.I cannot find out the way to resolve the error.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
          String to = "xyz@gmail.com";

          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          String from = "abc.com";

          // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
          String host = "localhost";

          // Get system properties
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          // Set response content type
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

          try{
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                      new InternetAddress(to));
             // Set Subject: header field
             String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
             String content=request.getParameter("mail");


             message.setSubject(subject);
             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText(content);
             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
             String title = "Send Email";
             String res = "Sent message successfully....";
             String docType =
             "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
             "transitional//en\">\n";
             out.println(docType +
             "<html>\n" +
             "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
             "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
             "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
             "<p align=\"center\">" + res + "</p>\n" +
             "</body></html>");
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }

    }
```

I am getting the following error in my console:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:312)
>     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
>     ... 29 more

Comment: `String from = "abc.com";` - This is not a valid email address in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an SMTP server running on `localhost`, and you are telling the API to use `localhost` as your mail server.

You either need to install a local SMTP server, or set the smtp hostname to a server you have access to, something like:

```
      String host = "smtp.yourisp.com"; // real server name required here

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to install smtp server on local box or use some existing smtp server(like yahoo, gmail etc . you can get the smtp settings on internet). You can use apache james server and make aware the mail sending api about it.